# Which Spark version should I download to run on top of Hadoop 3.1.2?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

In Spark download [page](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) we can choose between releases 3.0.0-preview and 2.4.4.

For release 3.0.0-preview there are the package types

- Pre-built for Apache Hadoop 2.7
- Pre-built for Apache Hadoop 3.2 and later
- Pre-built with user-provided Apache Hadoop
- Source code

For release 2.4.4 there are the package types

- Pre-built for Apache Hadoop 2.7
- Pre-built for Apache Hadoop 2.6
- Pre-built with user-provided Apache Hadoop
- Pre-built with Scala 2.12 and user-provided Apache Hadoop
- Source code

Since there isn't a *Pre-built for Apache Hadoop 3.1.2* option, can I download a *Pre-built with user-provided Apache Hadoop* package or should I download *Source code*?

Comment: Good question. I didn't try to it yet but according to this link you can download the Pre-built for Apache Hadoop 2.7 : http://www.techguru.my/programming/install-spark-2-3-x-on-yarn-with-hadoop-3-x/

Comment: I would have though 2.4.3 would be OK as well... based AWS EMR

Comment: I tried the Pre-built for Apache Hadoop 2.7 and got the warn `NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable` when I run spark-shell

Comment: That is a warning, not a Spark error and doesn't prevent any code from running

Comment: So is that correct: If I'm running Hadoop 3.1.2 I should download Spark 3.0.0 Pre-built for Hadoop 2.7?

Comment: @zperee Upgrade to Hadoop 3.2, then use pre built version for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are comfortable building source code, then that is your best option.

Otherwise, you already have a Hadoop cluster, so pick "user-provided" and copy your relevant core-site.xml, hive-site.xml, yarn-site.xml, and hdfs-site.xml all into the `$SPARK_CONF_DIR`, and it hopefully mostly will work

Note: DataFrames don't work on Hadoop 3 until Spark 3.x - [SPARK-18673](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18673)